# Laravel - Eloquent "Has", "With", "WhereHas" - What do they mean?

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relational-database, relationship

I've found the concept and meaning behind these methods to be a little confusing, is it possible for somebody to explain to me what the difference between `has` and `with` is, in the context of an example (if possible)?

Comment: **See also** stackoverflow.com/[Laravel "scope" query inside join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70678024/laravel-how-to-use-model-scope-method-inside-join-query)

Answer (score 927, accepted):

### With

`with()` is for **eager loading**. That basically means, along the main model, Laravel will preload the relationship(s) you specify. This is especially helpful if you have a collection of models and you want to load a relation for all of them. Because with eager loading you run only one additional DB query instead of one for every model in the collection.

Example:

`User > hasMany > Post`

```
$users = User::with('posts')->get();
foreach($users as $user){
    $users->posts; // posts is already loaded and no additional DB query is run
}
```

### Has

`has()` is to filter the selecting model based on a relationship. So it acts very similarly to a normal WHERE condition. If you just use `has('relation')` that means you only want to get the models that have at least one related model in this relation.

Example:

`User > hasMany > Post`

```
$users = User::has('posts')->get();
// only users that have at least one post are contained in the collection
```

### WhereHas

`whereHas()` works basically the same as `has()` but allows you to specify additional filters for the related model to check.

Example:

`User > hasMany > Post`

```
$users = User::whereHas('posts', function($q){
    $q->where('created_at', '>=', '2015-01-01 00:00:00');
})->get();
// only users that have posts from 2015 on forward are returned
```

Comment: +1, very helpful answer! Note also that while `with('relation')` will include the related table's data in the returned collection, `has('relation')` and `whereHas('relation')` will *not* include the related table's data. So you may need to call both `with('relation')` as well as `has()` or `whereHas()`.

Comment: Greet Answer,
How to access parent model from relationship model for instance here how to search post model based on the attributes of user model

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a lot about it in the docs... [This is all I found](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) (it's a few paragraphs down)

Comment: @hussainfrotan the same way, use `whereHas` on user relation when querying post.

Comment: Curious, in Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships , when using `whereHas` it uses `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;` which then is with `function(Builder $query)`. Most examples that I seen, dot use the `Builder`, just pass in the $query, which is the right way?

Comment: can you help me to solve my problem? i think you can help me

Comment: @Guntar if you mean the example is like this `function($query)...` it is the same thing without the type hints.

Comment: @lukasgeiter worthing updating answer Laravel 9.16 includes a `withWhereHas`

Answer (score 87):

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) has already explained the usage, so I will use SQL to explain the methods.

### Example:

Assuming there is an `Order (orders)` has many `OrderItem (order_items)` and you already built the relationship between them:

```php
// App\Models\Order:
public function orderItems() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OrderItem', 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

These three methods are **all based on a relationship**.

### with

**Result:** `with()` return the model object and its related results.

**Advantage:** It is **eager-loading** which can **prevent the N+1 problem**.

When you are using the following Eloquent Builder:

```php
Order::with('orderItems')->get();
```

Laravel change this code to **only two SQL**:

```sql
// get all orders:
SELECT * FROM orders; 
 
// get the order_items based on the orders' id above
SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE order_items.order_id IN (1,2,3,4...);
```

And then Laravel merges **the results of the second SQL query** with **the results of the first SQL** by **foreign key**, finally returning the collection results.

So if you selected columns without the foreign_key in a closure, the relationship result will be empty:

```php
Order::with(['orderItems' => function($query) { 
           // $query->sum('quantity');
           $query->select('quantity'); // without `order_id`
       }
])->get();

#=> result:
[{  id: 1,
    code: '00001',
    orderItems: [],    // <== is empty
  },{
    id: 2,
    code: '00002',
    orderItems: [],    // <== is empty
  }...
}]
```

### has

`Has` will return the model's object when **its relationship is not empty**.

```php
Order::has('orderItems')->get();
```

Laravel changes this code to **one SQL query**:

```sql
select * from `orders` where exists (
    select * from `order_items` where `orders`.`id` = `order_items`.`order_id`
)
```

### whereHas

The methods `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` put `where` conditions on your `has` queries. These methods allow you to add **customized constraints to a relationship constraint**.

```php
Order::whereHas('orderItems', function($query) {
   $query->where('status', 1);
})->get();
```

Laravel changes this code to **one SQL query**:

```sql
select * from `orders` where exists (
    select * 
    from `order_items` 
    where `orders`.`id` = `order_items`.`order_id` and `status` = 1
)
```