# 2 foreign keys on one column in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, database-relations

here's my database schema

[image]

and I have these models:

- Admin
- User
- Bet
- Match
- Team

I'm confused how to define the relationShip between `matches` and `teams` in models
here Is what I did till now...

**User.php**

```
public function bets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Bet');
}
```

**Bet.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');
}

public function match()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Match');
}
```

**Match.php**

```
public function bets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Bet');
}

//?????????????
```

**Team.php**

```
//?????????????
```

---

actually what I need Is the code that should be placed instead of `//???...` in both `Team.php` and `Match.php` so that I can easily do such things...

```
$team->matches();
$match->team1();
$match->team2();
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

**Match.php**

```
public function team1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Team', 'team1_id');
}

public function team2()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Team', 'team2_id');
}
```

**Team.php**

```
public function matches()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Match', 'team1_id')
                ->orWhere('team2_id', $this->id);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work..., I did this `return dd($team->matches()->where('id' ,'=', 1)->get());` and this is the error **Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'football_bet.match_team' doesn't exist**

Comment: Just edited.. can you please verify it again? `dd($team->matches()->find(1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which column should be targeted for each relationship:

```
public function team1() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Match', 'team1_id');
    }
 public function team2() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Match', 'team2_id');
    }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this. Give it a try.

1. Match.php

   ```
   public function team1(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'team1_id');
   }

   public function team2(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'team2_id');
   }
   ```
2. Team.php

   ```
   public function matches1(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Match', 'team1_id', 'id');
   }

   public function matches2(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Match', 'team2_id', 'id');
   }
   ```

Comment: work's fine, thank you , but how can I access all the matches that the team was In?  no matter It was the first team or second one , Is It the only way to join the array results?

Comment: Use with(). example: Team::with('matches1', 'matches2'). to learn more check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean