# Filtering in Eloquent (Laravel) by columns on tables referenced by foreign keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to filter by a keyword in a table which doesn't contain actual data by itself but only foreign keys to other tables. The problem is that I can't just write Incident::where(...) because that would filter by the foreign keys ids and not the data they contain.
By the way, the column by which I would like to filter is always called "name" in the referenced table.

To clarify:
I have a table 'incidents' with foreign keys like 'contact_method_id' and 'requested_by_id' and I would like to filter the rows of the incidents table by a keyword like 'john' and instead of comparing 'john' to the 'contact_method_id' or 'requested_by_id' I would like to compare it both to 'contact_methods.name' and 'users.name'.

Does anyone know if this is possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you mean the wherehas method?

Comment: Wow, I think whereHas just nails it. You won't imagine how many hours I've spent trying to solve this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just in case someone else lands here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations