# Laravel Polymorphic Many To Many Fetch By Specific Association

Tags: laravel, eloquent, octobercms

I have a *simple* many-to-many polymorphic relationship (if such thing is possible):

Authors:
On Blog we have Posts => Authorable
On Magazine, Articles => Authorable

Both relationships work as expected/documented. What I need is to fetch All authors for a specific Post category

All I have is: `Post::category('blue')` Collection (category being a scope). Based on that, what is the best way to get Authors that wrote "Blue Posts" ?

Comment: Do you want to eager load all author for specific category?

Comment: Exactly ... I want a collection of Authors that has Posts in Blue category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look into using the `has()` and `whereHas()` query methods within your scope. See [Laravel - Eloquent "Has", "With", "WhereHas" - What do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean) for a detailed explanation on using them.

Basically would look something like this:

```
$authorsOfBluePosts = Author::whereHas('posts', function ($postsQuery) {
    $postsQuery->whereHas('category', function ($categoryQuery) {
        $categoryQuery->where('name', 'blue');
    });
})->get();
```