# Laravel Eloquent Many-to-Many query whereIn

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

In my application I have updated a relationship from `one-to-many` to `many-to-many` and I'm trying to figure out a way to persist associated functionality.

Let's say I have two related tables, e.g. dogs and owners. If I have an array of owners and I'm trying to get a list of dogs id's for those owners, how should I do it eloquently?

Similar question was asked here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/getting-many-to-many-related-data-for-an-array-of-elements

So, How would I get the `Dog` models where `Owner` is in an array ?

Same thing as `$associatedDogs = Dog::whereIn('owner_id',$ListOfOwners)->get();` is for a `One-To-Many` relationship, but for `Many-to-Many`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$dogs = Dog::whereHas('owners', function($q) use($ownerIds) {
    $q->whereIn('id', $ownerIds);
})->get();
```

Comment: Should I choose the `whereHas` over `with` ? What is the difference between them in this case? Does it even make any difference?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the explaination here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30232227/2012740

Comment: @AngelinCalu yes, `with()` will not work for you, since it loads relation data.

Comment: @ I haven't actually tried the `with` method because of what I have read. So if I understood correctly, that it will probably work also, however it will eager load the `owner`s associated with the `dog`s

Comment: @AngelinCalu no `with()` will not work. It will load all dogs and filtered owners. `whereHas()` will load only dogs with owners which are in the list. Just try both and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Says Ambiguous Id in where clause is there any solution to that ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the two suggested solutions but I was getting an error that said that id was not unique.
I solved like this:

```
$dogs = Dog::whereHas('owners', function($q) use($ownerIds) {
    $q->whereIn('owner_id', $ownerIds);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$associateDogs = Dog::with(['owners' => function($query) use ($listOfOwners) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $listOfOwners);
}])->get();
```