# Laravel: How to get records from a pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm using  Lumen 5.1, I have many to many relation between tasks and users

Task model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Auth\User', 'task_user');
}

public function domain()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Domain', 'domain_id');
}
```

User model

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'task_user');
}
```

UserTask model

```
class UserTask {}
```

I want to search the get the user of the task, my code is

```
$tasks = Task::Where(function ($query) use ($domainId) {
    $query->where("domain_id", $domainId)
        ->where("is_done", 0)
        ->orwherehas('tasks.user.id', \Auth::id)
        ->orderBy('due_date', 'DESC');
})
->orWhere(function ($query) use ($domainId) {
    $query->where("domain_id", $domainId)
        ->Where("is_done", 1)
        ->Where("closed_dated", Carbon::today())
        ->orwherehas('tasks.user.id', \Auth::id)
        ->orderBy('closed_date', 'ASC');
})
->get();
```

My question is `whereHas` correct? Is `tasks.user.id` correct? Can I get to the user's id that way? I did it that way because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691421/laravel-eloquent-many-to-many-query-wherein)

The tech lead tells me that my code is wrong, he would you use `where`, he said that `whereHas` when you want to run a closure.

**Migrations:**

Tasks

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create($this->getTable(), function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('submit_date');
        $table->dateTime('closed_date');
        $table->dateTime('due_date');
        $table->tinyInteger('is_done')->default(0);

        $table->integer('domain_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('domain_id')->references('id')
            ->on(self::getTableName('domains'))->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->bigInteger('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')
            ->on(self::getTableName('auth_users', false))->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->bigInteger('closed_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('closed_by')->references('id')
            ->on(self::getTableName('auth_users', false))->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop($this->getTable());
}
```

task_user

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create($this->getTable(), function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')
            ->on(self::getTableName('tasks'))
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
            ->on(self::getTableName('auth_users', false))
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });

}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop($this->getTable());
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you wanting to get the tasks that have been assigned to a user that have either been completed today or not completed at all?

Comment: @RossWilson Please refer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464283/laravel-is-it-possible-to-do-orwheremodelfind) A task can be created by one user and assigned to many users, there's a many to many relationship between tasks and users

Comment: @RossWilson I want to find all tasks that are either created by or assigned to a user, if they are not completed or if they are closed today. So a user can see all of his open tasks + the tasks that he closed today, if the tasks are open, they should be sorted by the one having the worst due date, meaning by urgency

Comment: Please could you add your migrations (or just the table structures) for `tasks` and `task_user`?

Comment: @RossWilson Just added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `whereHas` would not be correct for both here. Also, you wouldn't be saying `whereHas('tasks...')` on the `Task` model.

**NB**

The 2nd param for `whereHas` should be a closure (function) and `Auth::id` should be `Auth::id()`. You can also use the `auth()` helper function instead of the `Auth` facade if you want to.

The following should give you what you want:

```
$tasks = Task::where("domain_id", $domainId)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($domainId) {
        $query
            ->where("is_done", 0)

            //whereHas - 1st arg = name of the relationship on the model, 2nd arg = closure
            ->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', auth()->id());
            });
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($domainId) {
        $query
            //If "is_done" = 1 only when it's been closed then you won't need to check "is_done"
            ->where("is_done", 1)
            ->where('closed_by', auth()->id())
            ->whereDate("closed_dated", '>=', Carbon::today()->startOfDay());
    })
    ->orderBy('due_date', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('closed_date', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post covers a one to many task assignment example.

https://medium.com/@brice_hartmann/building-a-user-based-task-list-application-in-laravel-eff4a07e2688

Getting tasks for current user, Relation on belongsToMany to the User model would be:

```
Auth::user()->tasks()->where('is_done',0) .... ->get();
```

Getting tasks with users:

```
Tasks::with(['user'])->where('is_done',1) ... ->get();
```

Authed user conclusion ... I am not 100% sure this is correct:

```
Auth::user()->tasks()
    ->where('domain_id', $domainId)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_done', 1)
              ->orWhere(function($query) {
                 $query->where('is_done', 0)
                       ->where('closed_dated', Carbon::today())
            });
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: so then, to get the task id from user, it becomes `task.user.id`?

Comment: I see, I went over what you posted again, I have updated my answer with what I think i can understand you want..

Comment: Your second answer is exactly what I want Sir, the only thing is that it gets all tasks for all users, I want to get all tasks for only the authorized user.

Comment: So you mean the date closed query? Auth:user()->tasks()->where('is_done',1)->orWhere('closed_dated', Carbon::today()) ? You gust need to mod that to group the OR to include domain_id

Comment: I added a conclusion, I think that is possible but i never had to write such a nested query before..

Comment: Interesting, not sure that works, will give it a try tonight and let you know