# Laravel: How to get records by using the pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, lumen

I have a many to many relationship between task and users, I am trying to get archived tasks, an archived task is:

- A task that `is_done = 1`
- A task that was done yesterday or before, not including tasks finished today
- A user can only see archived tasks that he created or he was assigned
  to, if a user is assigned to a task, his id is stored in the pivot
  table
- For reasons outside the scope of the question, I can only get to users by using the pivot table as shown in Task.php below.

Task.php model

```
public function taskUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tasks\UserTask')->where('role',1);
}
```

UserTask.php model contains nothing, an empty model

```
class UserTask extends BaseModel { }
```

Migrations

```
class CreateTasksTable extends Migration
{
    protected $table = 'tasks';
    protected $app_table = true;


    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->getTable(), function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->dateTime('submit_date');
            $table->dateTime('closed_date')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('due_date')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('is_done')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->integer('domain_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('domain_id')->references('id')
                ->on(self::getTableName('domains'))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')
                ->on(self::getTableName('auth_users', false))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('closed_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('closed_by')->references('id')
                ->on(self::getTableName('auth_users', false))->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop($this->getTable());
    }
}
```

and

```
class CreateTaskUsersTable extends Migration
{
    protected $table = 'task_user';
    protected $app_table = true;
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->getTable(), function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')
                ->on(self::getTableName('tasks'))
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
                ->on(self::getTableName('auth_users', false))
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('role');
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop($this->getTable());
    }
}
```

The actual tables respectively

[image]

and

[image]

My code:

The helper is below

```
    public static function getArchived($domainId, $userId)
    {
        Task::where("domain_id", $domainId)
            ->where("is_done", 1)
            ->where("closed_date", '<', Carbon::today()->startOfDay())

            ->where(function ($query) use ($userId) {
                $query->whereHas('taskUsers', function ($query) use ($userId) {
                    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
                });
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($userId) {
                $query->where('created_by', $userId);
            })
->get();
    }
```

The Action:

```
public function execute()
{
    $domainId = $this->request->get('domain_id');
    $userId = \Auth::id();
    $tasks = TasksHelper::getArchived($domainId,$userId);
    return $this->response->statusOk(['tasks' => $tasks]);
}
```

I just get a status OK, no result, tasks array is null, although my code seems to be correct and the tables contain 1 record which should have been returned.

Comment: in your getArchived() method I think you need to place a `return` before the `Task::` so it would look like `return Task::where(whatever condition)->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the return statement in your `getArchived` method. Also, the `orWhere` condition seems out of place. You must use [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping) if you need the 1st three conditions to apply as well. Otherwise the query reads `(1 && 2 && 3 && 4) || 5` whereas you need `1 && 2 && 3 && (4 || 5)`.

```
public static function getArchived($domainId, $userId)
{
    return Task::where("domain_id", $domainId)
        ->where("is_done", 1)
        ->where("closed_date", '<', Carbon::today()->startOfDay())

        ->where(function ($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->whereHas('taskUsers', function ($query) use ($userId) {
                $query->where('user_id', $userId);
            })->orWhere('created_by', $userId);
        })->get();
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you, everything is working now, I can award you the bounty in 16 hours from now according to stackoverflow