# Query HasManyThrough Laravel relation retrieving related records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Considering the basic example Has Many Through relationship in the Laravel guide, I'm trying to query directly with eloquent, countries with posts from type 100 (just an example).

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string
    type_id - integer
```

*type_id in posts is my peculiar case..*

So, I created a relationship in the country model that creates a relation with posts through users. The result that I want to achieve is a list of countries and within each country the posts created by users of that country.

```
//Country.php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'Post', 'User', 'country_id', 'user_id'
    );
}
```

I was able to replicate the result I want to achieve in other ways, but I would like to know why the eloquent query below does not return the expected result:

```
   $postsGroupedByCountries = Country::with([
        'posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('type_id', 100);
        }
    ])->get();
```

The return of the query are several countries with all posts without data. What is the correct way to do this query with Laravel Eloquent?

**First try:**

```
$postsGroupedByCountries = Country::whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('type_id', 100);
})->get();
```

**Second try:**

```
$postsGroupedByCountries = Country::whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('type_id', 100)->groupBy('posts.id');
})->get();
```

**Third try:**

```
$postsGroupedByCountries = Country::whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('type_id', 100);
})->get();

$postsGroupedByCountries = $postsGroupedByCountries ->map(function($country){
     $country->load('posts');
     return $country;
});
```

And I've already tried inside the load to use a closure with where as well. But it also did not work. The result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `with` and `whereHas` for the query.  `whereHas` is going to constrain the `Country` query to only show countries with posts from the specified id but does not load those posts in the results.  `with()` will then eager load the `posts` in the results BUT since it is called after the first query executes it does not know about the `whereHas` constraint and since it has been passed no constraints it will load all of the posts for each country.  To load the `Country`'s posts with the same constraints you would need to pass that to the `with` method as well.

All put together it would look like:

```
$countries = Country::whereHas('posts', function($query) {
    return $query->where('type_id', 100);
})
->with(['posts' => function($query) {
    return $query->where('type_id', 100);
}])
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are eager loading all the posts with every country, that is why you're seeing them all. I would try modifying the query to this:

```
$postsGroupedByCountries = Country::whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('type_id', 100)
})->get();
```

See what that gets you returned.

Comment: But I want to provide data with the posts loaded. The whereHas will do it? I think that whereHas is only to condition.

Comment: I think it will return you the loaded posts, give it a try and see what the results are. I  have been referencing this post, btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean

Comment: The posts wasn't loaded. I guess that with where has is lazy loading. I need to make a foreach after the eloquent query and call $country->posts to get it and put inside country.

Comment: After using whereas, if I try to access its relations (`$country->posts`) I get the same result as my first attempt. Lots of disconnected posts.

Comment: Try adding a groupBy to the nested query like :`$query->where('type_id', 100)->groupBy('posts.id')`

Comment: Doesn't works to. Is it the case that I'm trying to do it in a way that would not be a 'good way'? I want to get Countries with Posts through a third table. Would not it be better to query entity entity and then join? Does Laravel solve my need with just one query?

Comment: I'll put my tries at the end of my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Country.php
public function postsOfTypeHundred()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'User', 'country_id', 'user_id')
        ->where('type_id', 100);
}
```

```
/**
 * Laravel ^9.15
 * In Controller 
 */
$countries = Country::withWhereHas('postsOfTypeHundred')->get();
```

```
/** Created By */
$countries[0]->posts[0]->user->name
```