# How to whereHas when use belongsToMany relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I got a problem, When try to use `whereHas` in this case

Table `users`.

```
----------------
| id | name    |
----------------
| 1  | AAA     |
| 2  | BBB     |
| 3  | CCC     |
----------------
```

Table `subjects`.

```
------------------
| id | title     |
------------------
| 1  | Subject 1 |
| 2  | Subject 2 |
------------------
```

Table `subject_user`.

```
------------------------
| user_id | subject_id |
------------------------
| 1       | 1          |
| 2       | 1          |
| 1       | 2          |
| 3       | 2          |
------------------------
```

in Subject Model

```
...

public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'subject_user');
}

...
```

When I want to find subject by `user_id` with this query.

In this case `Auth::id() == 1` and `$request->user_id == 3`

```
$subject = Subject::whereHas('User', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->whereIn('user_id', [Auth::id(), $request->user_id]);
})->get();
```

With this query, I got subjects `1` and `2`. That was a wrong result. That must got only subject `2`.

Then I try this.

```
$subject = Subject::whereHas('User', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('user_id', $request->user_id);
})->get();
```

It would not get any subjects.

What query do I use in this case to get only subject `2`.

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)

Comment: May be us should use **users** instead of **User** in your query

Comment: `where->where` equals to `WHERE user_id=1 AND user_id=3` (never happens). Do you use `orWhere`?

Comment: you want to get subject id where with reference to current user ??

Answer (score 1):

@Lloople from your answer, I got an idea.

```
$subject = Auth::user()->Subject()->whereHas('User', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('user_id', $request->id);
})->first();
```

Comment: This will not work, since first you're filtering the subjects for the current logged in users, so you will search for another user's subjects when you already filtered that with the relation.

Comment: @Lloople No that's work. From query I got my subjects first. Then I use all of these to find subject between another user.

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it backwards? You already have the logged in user, so if you define the relationship in the `User` model you can do

```
$subjects = auth()->user()->subjects;
```

Anyway, you don't need to check double the `Auth::id()`and `$request->user_id`. In fact, I'm not sure you can do this last one.

Edit after comments

```
$subjects = Subject::whereBetween(auth()->user()->id, $request->user_id)->get();
```

You will need to change the order from the inputs, in case `$request->user_id` is less than `auth()->user()->id`or it wouldn't work.

Comment: That too close, But I'm not want all subjects of my user. I want subject between my user and specific user.

Comment: So you want both user's subjects? or all the subjects between them? For example user 2 and user 4 you want subjects for users 2 3 and 4

Comment: All the subjects between them (`Auth::user()` and another one)