# How to select in Laravel 5.6 Eloquent with parameters on multiple tables?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I need to run a select on multiple database tables using `Laravel 5.6` and I get parameters from the post `$request`. Now I need get back the records only if the give values are equvalent the record's values.

I want to do something like this, but this get back every client and section data, no matter what's happening in loan's query part:

```
Casefile::with([
    'client',
    'loan' => function($query) use($request) {
         $query->where('bank_name','REGEXP',$request->bank_name)
    },
    'section'
])->where($find)->get();
```

I want get back the entire record **only if** the `bank_name` is match with the `$request->bank_name`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try using whereHas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30232227/1672261

Comment: It seems good, but I need to use multiple tables in the select. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Casefile::with([
    'client',
    'section'
])->whereHas('loan', function($query) use($request) {
     $query->where('bank_name','REGEXP', $request->bank_name)
})->where($find)->get();
```