# Laravel Eloquent Pivot Tables filtered by pivot column on object collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've a problem and searching for a nice solution for it.

**I've these db tables:**

- game_objects
- game_object_attributes
- game_object_game_object_attribute (pivot)

**GameObject.php:**

```
public function gameObjectAttributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\GameObjectAttribute')->withPivot('value')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**GameObjectAttribute.php:**

```
public function gameObjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\GameObject');
    }
```

Now I'm trying to get all GameObject of an GameObjectType and filtering the result with pivot column 'value'.

```
$this->model->where('name', $gameObjectTypesEnum)->first()->gameObjects()->join('game_object_game_object_attribute', 'game_objects.id', '=', 'game_object_game_object_attribute.game_object_id')->where('value', '=', '4')->get());
```

I've used here an join but is there a way to do it with eloquent's relation?

This is returning me all GameObjects of type 'troops':

```
$this->model->where('name', $gameObjectTypesEnum)->first()->gameObjects()->get();
```

the 'gameObjects()' returning me a collection and here I can't call something like

```
$this->model->where('name', $gameObjectTypesEnum)->first()->gameObjects()->withPivot('value', 3)->get();
```

OR

```
$this->model->where('name', $gameObjectTypesEnum)->first()->gameObjects()->gameObjectAttributes->wherePivot('value', 3)->get();
```

Here I can iterate through collection 'gameObjects()' and checking with foreach if the pivot has value = 3 but there must be a better solution than this. I'm new to laravel..

**Additionally**

I try to get

1. Get all GameObjects by an GameObjectType =>  returning a collection**

   **GameObjectType::where('name', $gameObjectTypesEnum)->first()->gameObjects()**
2. Then I try to filtering trough pivot to get only GameObjects with given GameObjectType and with pivot value e.g. 3.

   **->join('game_object_game_object_attribute', 'game_objects.id', '=', 'game_object_game_object_attribute.game_object_id')->where('value', '=', '4')->get());**

I'm doing something wrong or this is not possible to do it with Eloquent :-(

Thank you all in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can do like this**

```
 $gameObjects = GameObject::where('name', $gameObjectTypesEnum)->whereHas('gameObjectAttributes', function($query)
    {
        $query->where('value', 3); 
    })->get();
```

Comment: I've tried your solution:

GameObjectType::where('name', $gameObjectTypesEnum)->first()->gameObjects()->with(array('gameObjectAttributes' => function($query)
        {
            $query->where('value', 3);
        }))->get());

This returns all GameObjects without considering where value = 3.  

SQL: "select * from "game_objects" where "game_objects"."game_object_type_id" = ? and "game_objects"."game_object_type_id" is not null"

Comment: that did the trick! Great thanks! But I'dont understand why whereHas is working?

Comment: To add an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misundertand it,

```
->wherePivot('value',4)
```

addition to your query is the eloquentish way of that join.

Comment: I thought so, too. Sql which is generated is this:
"select * from "game_objects" where "game_objects"."game_object_type_id" = ? and "game_objects"."game_object_type_id" is not null and "pivot" = ?"

there is no connection to pivot table.. and I don't know why...

Comment: eloquent may or may not use direct matching sql queries to get needed information. it can use additional small queries when the info will be used. (eager load, lazy load topic).

but i assume that you already tried with wherePivot method with a sample data and couldn't get the desired result. if that's the case, i have no other solution right now.

Comment: Yeah I've already test it with wherePivot and withPivot ... :-(