# Issue with Laravel Lazy Eager Loading

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

I have issue with taking data from database based on hasMany relations and send it to api in Larave.
Below code, Laravel do not give me product of Customer where Customer id = $id. I don't know why, I can't send $id next to $query. If I write number in '' I have good answear but I need take it automaticly.

```
$products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->q.'%')->orWhere('symbol', 'like', '%'.$request->q.'%')->with(['customers' => function ($query, $id) {
    $query->where('id', '=', $id);
}])->get();
```

all api code

```
Route::get('/customer/{id}/products', function(Request $request, $id){
   $customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);
   $products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->q.'%')->orWhere('symbol', 'like', '%'.$request->q.'%')->with(['customers' => function ($query, $id) {
       $query->where('id', '=', $id);
   }])->get();

   return $products;
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a variable inside the `with` method, you have to type `use($id)` after the `function($query)` like this code below.

```
$products = Product::where('name','like','%'.$request->q.'%')
    ->orWhere('symbol', 'like', '%'.$request->q.'%')
    ->with(['customers' => function ($query) use($id) {
         $query->where('id', '=', $id);
    }])->get();
```

If you need to find the **product** with those **Customer's** conditions you can use the `whereHas` function. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean) for further information.

Comment: Nothing mate. Just accept the answer, so others can see the result. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I`m newbie so I didn't know about accept, I'm sorry.