# Collection Relationship Select columns not working Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to select columns (id, title) of the relationship database (product_detail) but it's not working at all.

My Query:

```
RoomProduct::select('product_id', DB::raw('SUM(value) as total'))
          ->whereHas('room.offer', function($sql) use ($offer_id) {
              $sql->where('id', $offer_id);
          })->whereHas('product_detail', function($sql) use ($category_id) {
              $sql->select("id", "title")->with(['category' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('parent_id', $category_id);
            }])->orWhere('id', $category_id);
          })->groupBy("product_id")->get();
```

Comment: Can you include a little more information about your database schema, model relationships, and the expected result?

Comment: Database schema:

--RoomProduct  || select product_id, value
---Products (product_detail) || select title
----Category 

the query above is working fine and i get the product_id and the sum of value but i cant get any fields from nested table "product_detail" 

I need this output:
* Category_id
** Product_id, Total, Title (product_detail)

Comment: Because whereHas method is use only for apply condition on database.You need to use `with('product_detail')` method with `whereHas("product_detail")` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have a read of the top rated answer of this post -> *[Laravel - Eloquent "Has", "With", "WhereHas" - What do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)*

The `whereHas()` method is the same as the `has()` method except it allows you to provide additional where clauses inside of your closure. But both of these methods only return models that have the relationship you have asked for. This does not mean it will return any columns in those relationships though.

You will need to use the `with()` method to obtain the columns you are looking for and then reference them in your select as something like `select('product_id', DB::raw('SUM(value) as total'), 'product_detail.id', 'product_details.title')`

I hope this has helped you! If it's not clear or have any questions i'll be sure to respond as quick as possible.