# How to Write Sub Query in With()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to get specific data like "roles" table have filed **status** and i need **status** = 1 that all data get from the role table

```
$result = User::select()
    ->with('roles')
    ->where('email', $email)
    ->get();
    return $result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write subQuery like

```
$result = User::select()
    ->with(['roles' => function($q){    
         $q->where('status', 1);
    }])
    ->where('email', $email)
    ->get();
    return $result;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is select() needed? Should I correct my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Following the answers to this question: [Laravel - Eloquent "Has", "With", "WhereHas" - What do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)
If I understood correctly how your data model is structured:

- User has many Roles
- Role has a property status
- Want to filter by status = 1

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){
    $q->where('status', '1');
})
->where('email', $email)
->get();
```

EDIT: I am not happy with the answer above because in that case as far as I understood, the Users returned do not have the list of roles already loaded, so I checked the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) and given what I found, the following code should do what you ask:

```
$users = User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', '1');
}])
->where('email', $email)
->get();
```

I never used eloquent nor laravel and I am not a php developer, so I could not try this snippet, please if it is not correct let me know.

Comment: As a Laravel developer; You are correct. This code will fetch the users with their roles (eager loading) but just the users where the query for the roles returns true.