# Specify more complex conditions with Eloquent in hasMany()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a relationship between `permission` and `item_permission`. The problem is that I need to check if the two columns on each table match, `permission.op_id  = item_permission.op_id` and  `permission.screen_id = item_permission.screen_id`.

```php
class Permission extends Model
{
    public function itemPermission()
    {
        // This should also match the screen_id column in each table.
        return $this->hasMany('App\ItemPermission', 'op_id', 'op_id');
    }
}
```

Using SQL is easy; I use "and" in the inner join between permission and item_permission. But with Eloquent, I cannot achieve it. I've tried all day to solve this problem but I couldn't. I want to be able to use a query like the following.

```php
$permission->with('itemPermission)->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your top level relation is, but you are probably looking for `has`, or for more filter control, `wherehas`.  Generally this will help to select the secondary `hasMany` relationships where they exist.

The Laravel manual is pretty helpful [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships), but for a great explanation of the eloquent concepts in general, see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean).

Comment: @diego, if this answer helped you to get to your next question on how to use `has`, please mark it as accepted.