# return if id not null, laravel elequent

Tags: php, laravel

I have connected tables with a `hasMany` & `belongsTo` relationship.

Bridal Model:

```
public function plans()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Plan");
}
```

Plan Model:

```
public function bridal()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Bridal");
}
```

And I have an query that returns those data to endpoint.

```
public function bridal()
{

    $bridals = Bridal::with(["plans" => function($query){
        $query->orderBy("plans.plan_price");
    }])
    ->groupBy("place_name")
    ->get();


    return $bridals;

}
```

Everything is fine, except one thing. In Bridal table some of ID doesn't have plan. So when I return datas, some of `bridal id` comes with an empty `Plans` array.

[image]

I want to prevent that. If a `bridal id` doesn't have a plan, then I don't want to return that bridal id. How can I achieve what I want here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Has**. If you just use `has('relation')` that means you only want to get the models that have at least one related model in this relation.

```
$bridals = Bridal::with(["plans" => function($query){
        $query->orderBy("plans.plan_price");
    }])->has('plans')
    ->groupBy("place_name")
    ->get();
```

Check more info [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30232227/9978078)

Comment: thank you, also appreciate for explanation link. I will check it as answer.

Comment: Happy to help brother.

Answer (score 1):

Add whereHas() in your query : so you will get bridal records which has plans

```
$bridals = Bridal::with(["plans" => function($query){
       $query->orderBy("plans.plan_price");
   }])
   ->whereHas('plans')
   ->groupBy("place_name")
   ->get();
```