# Laravel/Lumen - Using Model::with()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, relational-database, relationship

I have two tables:
Coretable and extensiontable_itc.
They are in a 1-n relationship, extensiontable_itc can have N records referencing 1 record on coretable.

If understood correctly, I learnt here
[Laravel - Eloquent "Has", "With", "WhereHas" - What do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)

that `model::with('relatedModel')->get()` can fetch me all the records from coretable and extensiontable_itc wherever the coretablerecords are referenced by the extensiontable_itc records.

However, when I apply this to my code like here:

```
$join = coretable::with('extensiontable_itc')->get();
log::info($join);
```

I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'extensiontable_itc.extensiontable_itc' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `extensiontable_itc` where `extensiontable_itc`.`extensiontable_itc` in (1))
```

As far as I understand, its looking for a column "extensiontable_itc" on my extensiontable_itc table. This of course cant work, but I dont understand why this happens?
The foreign keys are in place in my db, and the respective models should be fine, here is their code:

coretable.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CoreTable extends Model
{

  /**
  * The table associated with the model.
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $table = 'coretable';
  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'Internal_key'
  ];



  /**
   * Many-To-Many relationship with User-Model.
   */
  public function extensiontable_itc()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\extensiontable_itc', 'extensiontable_itc');
  }

  public function inaccessibletable()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\inaccessibletable', 'inaccessibletable');
  }
}
```

extensiontable_itc.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class extensiontable_itc extends Model
{

  /**
  * The table associated with the model.
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $table = 'extensiontable_itc';
  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'description'
  ];



  /**
   * Many-To-Many relationship with User-Model.
   */
  public function coretable()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\coretable', 'coretable');
  }
}
```

And here is an overview of the foreign keys in my DB:

```
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME                         | COLUMN_NAME                 | CONSTRAINT_NAME                      | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME    | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+
| ad_usersxad_groups                 | Ad_user_id                  | fk_ad_groupxad_user                  | ad_users                 | id                     |
| ad_usersxad_groups                 | Ad_group_id                 | fk_ad_userxad_group                  | ad_groups                | id                     |
| extensiontables_registryxad_groups | ad_group_id                 | fk_ad_groupxextensiontables_registry | ad_groups                | id                     |
| extensiontables_registryxad_groups | extensiontables_registry_id | fk_extensiontables_registryxad_group | extensiontables_registry | id                     |
| extensiontable_itc                 | coretable_id                | fk_extensiontable_itc_coretable      | coretable                | id                     |
| inaccessibletable                  | coretable_id                | fk_inaccessibletable_coretable       | coretable                | id                     |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> return $this->hasOne('App\ModelName', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

The problem occurs because when you are using `with('extensiontable_itc')`;

laravel according to your relationship method `extensiontable_itc` to find the foreign_key, and what you given is `extensiontable_itc`, and you don't have this column,

Change to your `extensiontable_itc` to `coretable_id` in the hasOne method:

```php
  public function extensiontable_itc()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\extensiontable_itc', 'coretable_id');
  }
```

and `coretable` has one `extensiontable_itc`, `extensiontable_itc` belongs to `coretable`, you need to fine the inverse of a hasOne relationship using the belongsTo method:

```php
  public function coretable()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\coretable', 'coretable_id');
  }
```

More reference: [one-to-one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)