# Laravel query not using where clause for date

Tags: sql, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I have made a laravel query which gets all the data but does not use the where clause for **$startdate.**

```
$user->studentGroups()->with([
            'GroupTasks' => function ($queryTwo) use ($startdate)

    { return $queryTwo->where('start_date', '>', $startdate); } // THIS LINE IS NOT WORKING!!

    ])->with(['GroupTasks.prgressList' => function ($queryThree) use ($student_id)
    { return $queryThree->where('progress_student_task_users.mis_id', $student_id); },
        'GroupTasks.studentViews' => function ($queryfour) use ($student_id){ return $queryfour->where('student_task_user_vieweds.mis_id', $student_id)->latest(); },
    ])->get();
```

Without the start date working it just gets all the data which is not really the idea.
Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Hi Sam,

Do you have the original query that you're using for the '$queryTwo' argument?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Eloquent "Has", "With", "WhereHas" - What do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)

Comment: @RobertYoung $queryTwo is just part of the query builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$user->studentGroups()
    ->with([
        'GroupTasks' => function ($query) use ($startdate, $student_id) {
            return $query->whereDate('start_date', '>', $startdate)
            ->with([
                'prgressList' => function ($query) use ($student_id) {
                    return $query->where('progress_student_task_users.mis_id', $student_id);
                },
                'studentViews' => function ($query) use ($student_id) {
                    return $query->where('student_task_user_vieweds.mis_id', $student_id)->latest();
                },
            ]);
        }

    ])->get();
```

Comment: No, I keep getting the error: Undefined variable: student_id

Answer (score 0):

Try using `whereDate()` instead.

```php
return $queryTwo->whereDate('start_date', '>', $startdate)
```

Also, try casting `start_date` fields to date by adding something like below to your `GroupTask` model:

```php
protected $dates = [
    'start_date',
    'end_date'
];
```

You can read more about attribute casting here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: I don't think its the date, looking at debug bar the query does not use the where clause in the statement.

Comment: Try committing out the second `with()`. The first with() statement is probably overloaded by the second statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I move the **->get()** to just after the where clause it gets the data including start date but does not include the rest of the with's!

```
$user->studentGroups()->with([
            'GroupTasks' => function ($queryTwo) use ($startdate)

    { return $queryTwo->where('start_date', '>', $startdate); } // THIS LINE IS NOT WORKING!!

    ])->get() // ADD GET() HERE NOW WORKS

->with(['GroupTasks.prgressList' => function ($queryThree) use ($student_id)
        { return $queryThree->where('progress_student_task_users.mis_id', $student_id); },
            'GroupTasks.studentViews' => function ($queryfour) use ($student_id){ return $queryfour->where('student_task_user_vieweds.mis_id', $student_id)->latest(); },
    ])->get();
```