# Laravel Eloquent - orWhereHas method - When to use it and how

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to understand some advanced eloquent commands and on the Laravel official documentation, there is not so much about the Eloquent orWhereHas method and there isn't also an example about how it works.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Can somebody help me to understand it with also a simple example?

Comment: Do you have any ambiguity about `whereHas` or just about `orWhereHas`?

Comment: The signature is the same as `whereHas`.

Comment: look at answer here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How** to use it: just chain as any other `Eloquent` method

```php
User::whereHas(...)->orWhereHas(...)->get();
```

**When** to use it: imagine you have `Users`, `Posts` and `Comments`, and each user can write posts and comments. Then you need to get *active* users. For example, you assume *active* as user, who has made posts OR comments last 7 days. So, you can get it this way:

```php
$users = App\Models\User::query()
    ->whereHas('posts', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7));
    })
    ->orWhereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7));
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting it.
There is just an imperfection in your code. You miss the >= to get the values of last week.
$query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(7));

Comment: If you fix this I can accept yours as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Say there's a blog kind of app. The main entity/model of the app would be Post (Blog Post).

When any author writes and publishes a Post,

- visitors to the blog site can leave Comment(s) for the Post
- visitors can Like a Post

So we have 3 models here

- **Post** - which can ***have many*** **Comment(s)**
- **Post** - can ***have many*** **Like(s)**

> Now let's say for some reason we want to get all Post records from the database which either have 10 or more comments in the current month or 3 or more likes in the current month

We can write a query like

```php
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function($query) {
        $query->where('created_at', '>', now()->startOfMonth();
    }, '>=', 10)
    ->orWhereHas('likes', function($query){
        $query->where('created_at', '> ', now()->startOfMonth();
    }, '>=', 3)
    ->get();
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Just like `where` both `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` accepts closure as 2nd argument for more fine grained query control.

Actually `whereHas` is supposed to be used when you want to have more power on constraints.

If you just want to check the existence of relation records you can use `has` for eg:

> Get all post records which either have comment or like and paginate 20 per page

```php
$postsWithCommentsOrLikes = Post::has('comments')
    ->orHas('likes')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: as far i understood, your code example can be changed from `whereHas` to `has`, because you are using no callbacks to filter subqueries

Comment: Yes true I was just adding that but got distracted with something else

Comment: In this case, if you specify any condition I think you can just use has and orHas

Comment: Yes @DavideCasiraghi if the requirement is to just check whether model has related records or not then simple `has()` and `orHas()` can suffice. However if more fine grained control is required to create a complex constraint on relationship check then `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` come into play as both these accept closure as second parameter where complex query logic can be defined. Have update answer for both scenarios