# How do i get all the Units that satisfy the criteria of being in a certain city (where city is a column in the Property Table)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

Property Model:

```
class Property extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'properties';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'address', 'city', 'poskod', 'state', 'facilities'];


    /* Get all the units in this property */
    public function units()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Unit::class);
    }
}
```

Unit Model

```
   class Unit extends Model { 
   use HasFactory;

   protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'property_id',
        'type',
        'no',
        'owner',
        'commission',
        'agent',
        'availability',
        'bed',
        'bath',
        'sqft',
        'rental',
        'sale',
    ];
   
   /* Get the property the unit is in */
   public function property() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
   }
}
```

I need to get all the units which are in a certain city. And city is defined inside a property which is a foreign key to units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by memory, so it is not tested.

```
$units = Unit::with('property')
    ->whereHas('property' function ($query) {
        $query->where('city', 'Amsterdam');
    });
```

Very good explanation of eager loading and whereHas here: [Laravel - Eloquent "Has", "With", "WhereHas" - What do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)