# Laravel how to use model scope method inside join query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

**i want to use scope method inside join subquery so is there any way I can do that in laravel?**

**Post Model**

```
    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        return $query->where('published',true);
    }
```

Now I want to join user table with post table but in join I want to use this scope method directly but its giving me error.

```
Users::join('posts',function($q){
    $q->on('posts.user_id','users.id');
    $q->published();

})->get();
```

**So is there any way I can use scope directly inside join subquery ?**

Comment: **See also** stackoverflow.com/[Eloquent "Has", "With", "WhereHas" meanings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add the relation between posts and users to the User model like so:

**User Model**

```
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

and then your scope stays as it is, and your query if you wanna get users with their published posts:

```
 return User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
                $query->published();
            }])
            ->get();
```

and if you want to get only users that have published posts:

```
return User::whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
                $query->published();
           })
           ->get();
```

> **Note** that while `with('posts')` will include the related table's data in the returned collection, `whereHas('posts')` will **not** include the related table's data.
>
> Hence sometimes you may need to call both together, I mean, only `with('posts')` will **eager load** relations (in this case `posts`).

Comment: but I want user who has published post else I don't wont them in array

Comment: then the second query with the **whereHas**, would get you all users that have at least 1 published post