# show relation table based on the parent table column in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to show the `ProductAttributes` relation based on the product's `attribute_status` column.

Here is my code:

```php
Product::with('productImages', 'productReviews', 'user.vendors', 'subchildcategories', 'ProductAttributes')
    ->where('category_id', $request->category_id)
    ->where('products.status', 1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: attribute_status is in which table? products or product_attributes or is it named just status ?

Comment: Consider a relation in product model. Take a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)

Comment: attribute_status is in the Products table

Comment: @Rahumathulla If I understand you correctly, you are trying to eager load `ProductAttributes` only when `products.attribute_status ` is `1`? Because you can toggle display product attributes based on a simple `if` condition on the `attribute_status` field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
Product::where('category_id',$request->category_id)
    ->where('products.status',1)
    ->with('productImages', 'productReviews', 'user.vendors', 'subchildcategories', 'ProductAttributes')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$products = Product::with(['productImages', 'productReviews', 'user.vendors', 'subchildcategories', 'ProductAttributes'])
    ->where('category_id',$request->category_id)
    ->where('products.status',1)
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($product) {
        $product->productAttributes = $product->attribute_status == 1 ? $product->productAttributes : null;

        return $product;
    });
```