# How to a perform sorting on Array of Objects and Append the Lowest value to parent Array in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Response, that is of the following:

```
[{
      "id":7,
      "name": "Product Name",
      "versions":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "amount":199
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "amount":99
         }
      ]
}]
```

In Laravel Controller I did the following,

```
$q = Product::select(*)->with('getProductVersion');
$product = $q->WhereHas('getProductVersion', function($q){
           $q->orderBy('amount', 'asc'); })->get();

return $product;
```

`getProductVersion` is a ManytoMany relation between Product and Version.

However the Ordering isnt correct, the Expected result is

```
[{
      "id":7,
      "name": "Product Name",
      "lowest_amount": 99,
      "versions":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "amount":99
         },
         {
            "id":1,
            "amount":199
         }
      ]
}]
```

Sort the Array of Object and Print the lowest value to Parent Array.

Comment: You asked for `orderBy('amount', 'asc')` -- meaning the amount should be ascending, which is exactly what you got. If you want the smaller values last, use `orderBy('amount', 'desc')`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i have edited the question

Comment: `whereHas()` filters the parent Model's query, but doesn't return anything; you're getting the versions in the default order, since `with()` is the one that returns associated records, but you're not passing any sorting logic to `with()`. Use `with(['getProductVersion' => function ($q) { // sorting logic here })])` or [`withWhereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence) if you need to both filter and sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `WhereHas`, and use `with`

```php
$q = Product::select('*')->with(['getProductVersion' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('amount', 'asc');
}])->get();
```

the with() method to eagerly load the getProductVersion relationship with a closure that orders the related versions by the amount attribute in ascending order

refer to this please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30232227/4613828

More if you need to assign the lowest value:

```php
$products = Product::with(['getProductVersion' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('amount', 'asc');
}])->get()->map(function($product) {
    $product->lowest_amount = $product->getProductVersion->min('amount') ?? null;
});

return $product;
```

Comment: Thankyou so much that fixed the sorting part. Now how can i append the sorted "lowest_amount" as a new column in the result ?

Comment: I think you should modify add some code handling this:
```php
if (!empty($product->versions)) {
    $product->lowest_amount = $product->versions[0]->amount ?? null;
} else {
    $product->lowest_amount = null;
}
```

Comment: Also, `versions` is not set, but `getProductVersion` is, so, more concise: `$product->lowest_amount = $product->getProductVersion->min('amount') ?? null;`

Comment: I did update, and used `map` to the item for version's lowest price, without doing another query - data already loaded

Comment: That's a little better, but still kinda crazy. First, `$product` is a bad variable name, since `->get()` returns multiple, so it should be `$products`. Next, defining variables for a single use, like `$lowest_version = ...`, then `$item->lowest_version = $lowest_version` is silly, as is `$versions->first() ? $versions->first()->amount : null`, then `$item->versions = $versions`; why are you assigning it again? You can literally do all of this in a single line: `$products = Product...->map(function ($product) { $product->lowest_amount = $product->getProductVersion->min('amount') ?? null; });`

Comment: I liked your attention to making the code clean and more readable variable name, for the `map` I will take your suggestion improvement to the answer, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253631/discussion-between-abdelrahman-m-allam-and-tim-lewis).

Comment: No problem  Ultimately this question isn't about optimization or anything like that, but Laravel provides a lot of useful methods. Apologies, I don't have time for chat right now, but cheers; answer looks great now!